# braintree into flutter web using JS got this error "options.selector or options.container must reference a valid DOM node"

Tags: javascript, flutter, braintree, flutter-web

Trying to implement Braintree payment gateway into flutter web.
Still no SDK for **flutter web** from Braintree. So trying to implement their javascript SDK.

Here is my js file

```
function payment(auth){
    var button = document.querySelector('submit-button');
    console.log(auth);
    console.log(button);
    braintree.dropin.create({
      authorization: auth,
      container: 'dropin-container'
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
        console.log(createErr);
        console.log(instance);
         button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) {
              // Submit payload.nonce to your server
              return payload.nonce
            });
         });
    });
}
```

Calling this js function from dart. Here is the complete dart code.

```
@JS()
library my_script;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js_util';

import 'package:carbonbins/model/model.dart';
import 'package:carbonbins/pages/navigation.gr.dart';
import 'package:carbonbins/utils/image_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

@JS()
external void initBraintree(auth);

@JS()
external String payment(auth);

class PaymentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserModel userModel;

  PaymentPage({@required this.userModel});

  @override
  _PaymentPageState createState() => _PaymentPageState();
}

class _PaymentPageState extends State<PaymentPage> {

  String auth = "sandbox_.....";

  void getButton() {
    var htmlL = """<div id="checkout-message"></div>
        <div id="dropin-container"></div>
    <button id="submit-button">Submit payment</button>""";

    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'payment-container',
        (int viewId) => DivElement()
          ..appendHtml(htmlL)
          ..style.border = 'none');

    print(HtmlElementView(
      viewType: "dropin-container",
    ));
  }

  void setupDropin() {
    print(auth);
    var status = payment(auth);
    print("Status: $status");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getButton();
    setupDropin();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 500.0,
              height: 300.0,
              child: HtmlElementView(
                viewType: "payment-container",
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I run this code, I see only the submit button in the screen. Got this error from web console,

```
"options.selector or options.container must reference a valid DOM node."
```

How can I integrate the Braintree payment into the **flutter web**?

or any other international payment gateway that works in flutter web.

Comment: were you able to get this working? I have been having trouble getting the actual payment nonce to return

Comment: hey @DanielN. basically, I switched to another framework, but now flutter in the stable channel, and ready for production, so you can try now.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Technical Disclaimer***: flutter-web is in beta and I would not recommend it to be used with any payment service. This might lead to critical issues and not advisable.

The `HtmlElementView` widget adds all its elements into shadowdom which is not directly accessible for the global javascript context. Check this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40080) here in github.

The solution would be to pass the `DivElement` reference to the external js function. For e.g. in your case

Create the div element out side the build method and hold a reference, like in initSate

```dart
DivElement paymentDiv;

@override
initState(){

// always call before rest of the logic.
super.initState();

var htmlL = """<div id="checkout-message"></div>
        <div id="dropin-container"></div>
    <button id="submit-button">Submit payment</button>""";
paymentDiv=  DivElement()
          ..appendHtml(htmlL)
          ..style.border = 'none');
// remaining logic

}
```

Then in your build/other method pass this element for the `registerViewFactory` method.

```dart
// ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'payment-container',
        (int viewId) => paymentDiv;
```

Set you JS interop to accept dynamic parameter.

```dart
@JS()
external String payment(dynamic auth);
```

Rewrite you Javascript to directly work with this element reference. e.g

```
function payment(auth){
    var button = auth;
    // Remaining logic
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the element reference of the button from paymentDiv to the payment JS function?

Comment: The container should be empty prior to creation of dropin instance